# CodeIgniter , PHP : Object Not Found

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter-3

When submitting form, I am getting the following error. Can you help to solve this error?

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. The
>   link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please
>   inform the author of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.17 (
>
> Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.20

Url is being displayed as http://localhost/dentalcare/c_register/do_insert

Code in config.php is

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/dentalcare/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

my form.php code
Im trying to use form_open, action in form, and a href but it don't work

```
<div id="register" class="text-center">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="section-title center">
      <h2>Register</h2>
      <?php
echo form_open('c_register/do_insert');
?>
      <hr>
      <form action="<?php echo base_url('c_register/do_insert'); ?>" method="post">
      <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/user/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
      <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
      <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
   <!--    <input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Retype Password"> -->
      <ul>
      <p1>Gender</p1>
      <select name="gender" id="" class="pilihan">
        <option value="men">Male</option>
        <option value="women">Female</option></select>
      </ul>
      <ul>
      <p1>Occupation</p1>
      <li><input type="radio" name="job" value="doctor" checked> Doctor<br></li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="job" value="nurse"> Nurse<br></li>
    </ul>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/user/login.css">
      <a href="<?php echo base_url('c_register/do_insert'); ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">Primary link</a>
  </form>
```

my controller code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class C_register extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('m_register');
    }
    function do_insert(){
        $firstname=$_POST['fname'];
        $lastname=$_POST['lname'];
        $fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $password=$_POST['pass1'];
        $gender=$_POST['gender'];
        $job=$_POST['job'];
        $passwordx = md5($password);
        $data_insert=array(
        'fname'=>$firstname,
        'lname'=>$lastname,
        'fullname'=>$fullname,
        'username'=>$username,
        'email'=>$email,
        'pass1'=>$passwordx,
        'gender'=>$gender,
        'job'=>$job
        );
        $res=$this->m_register->InsertData('member',$data_insert);
        if ($res >= 1){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan','tambah data sukses');
            redirect('dashboard');
        }else {
            echo "data gagal diinsert";
        }   
    }


}
?>
```

my model code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class M_register extends CI_Model {

    public function InsertData($tabelName, $data){
        $res=$this->db->insert($tabelName, $data);
        return $res;
    }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you using `.htaccess` on your root folder (to remove `index.php` part) ?

Comment: You haven't stated if you are using htaccess to remove index.php from the URL. And you haven't shown your form code to show how you are generating the action, so as a test if localhost/dentalcare/c_register/do_insert does not work, does localhost/dentalcare/index.php/c_register/do_insert work?

Comment: Im using .htacces  @HastaDhana

Comment: I've edited my question n add my form there, you can check it @TimBrownlaw

Comment: @NadiaKusumaPutri Why do you reopening the `form` tag after `form_open('c_register/do_insert')` ?

Comment: @NadiaKusumaPutri Does the htaccess contain a line like this : `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` or maybe you could also show the contents of the htaccess file?

Comment: I realize that my .htacces doesn't contain that code, n it works now @HastaDhana , Thannk you

Comment: Sure, glad it works.. ;)